# How to extract values from Pandas value_counts() results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After doing `df.['ColumnName'].value_counts()` to count unique strings in a column of a data frame, I get results in the following format:

```
a    4
b    2
c    5
Name: ColumnName, dtype: int64
```

How can I extract values from these results? For example, how can I get 'b' or 2?

Answer (score 2):

It is `Series`, so use methods [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html),
[`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html),
[`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html),
[`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
s = df['ColumnName'].value_counts()
```

**Test**:

```
s = pd.Series([4,2,5], index=['a','b','c'])

#get value by label
s.loc['b'] #2
s.at['b'] #2

#get value by position
s.iloc[1]  #2
s.iat[1]  #2
s[1] #2

#get index by value
s.index[s.eq(2)].item() #b

#get index value by position
s.index[1] #b
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally save it as a dict which I feel more comfortable manipulating

```
s = df['ColumnName'].value_counts().to_dict()

{'c': 5, 'a': 4, 'b': 2}

s['b'] #gives 2
```

Can get keys, values using  `.keys()`, `.values()`

Answer (score 1):

to extract `index` from df['ColumnName'].value_counts():
`df['ColumnName'].value_counts().index.tolist()`

to extract `values` from df['ColumnName'].value_counts():
`df['ColumnName'].value_counts().values.tolist()`

hence, to get `b`:
`df['name'].value_counts().index.tolist()[1]`

and to get `2`:
`df['name'].value_counts().values.tolist()[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use index to get the values from the series, for example

`df['ColumnName'].value_counts()[0]` output `4`

`df['ColumnName'].value_counts()[1]` output `2`

`df['ColumnName'].value_counts()[2]` output `5`

Or you could store the output in a DataFrame

```
pd.DataFrame(df['ColumnName'].value_counts())
```

output:

```
     ColumnName
a    4
b    2
c    5
```